# async/await native implementations

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

[This proposal](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#desugaring) suggests that `async` functions can use generator functions under the hood, although I cannot find a confirmation of this in ES2017 spec.

Moreover, when generator prototype becomes messed up in Chrome/Node.js, `async` functions don't seem to be affected, this suggests that `GeneratorFunction` isn't used by `AsyncFunction`, at least directly:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf((function * () {}).prototype).next = null;

(async () => {
    return await Promise.resolve(1);
})()
.then(console.log);
```

How exactly does `async`/`await` work in existing native implementations?

Are the implementations more performant than it would be possible with `Promise`/generator function approach that is suggested by the proposal and is usually implemented in Babel and TypeScript?

Comment: I believe `async - await` is using exactly the same mechanism with promises but parsed differently by the compiler. Before their native implementation one could get an abstraction (imperative looking asychronous code) similar to async-await  by using generators and promises as [explained here beautifully](https://curiosity-driven.org/promises-and-generators).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> How exactly does async/await work in existing native implementations?

If we look at the actual [native implementation of async await in v8](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/d08c0304c5779223d6c468373af4815ec3ccdb84/src/js/harmony-async-await.js#34) we can clearly see both promise and generator as the obvious basis of async-await implementation, also in the [parser](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/d08c0304c5779223d6c468373af4815ec3ccdb84/src/parsing/parser.cc#4008) it clearly states the generator-promise nature of desugaring async-await.

Regarding ES spec, even though the spec doesn't directly mention the actual implementation of execution context switching, it hints  usage of same [`Perform ! Call(promiseCapability.[[Resolve]]`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-async-functions-abstract-operations-async-function-start) mechanism the [`Promise.resolve`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-promise.resolve) is using. Thus subjectively hinting the possible "mechanism" to handle running execution context toggling of `asyncContext`.

> Moreover, when generator prototype becomes messed up in Chrome/Node.js, async functions don't seem to be affected, this suggests that GeneratorFunction isn't used by AsyncFunction, at least directly:

Both `generator` and `async` functions in the runtime are descendants of the `Function` object, they don't inherit from one another though, that's why you don't see the committed changes.

But the actual native level implementation of specific host object or method doesn't have to necessarily be connected to runtime execution of compiled counterparts and their dependencies, the same way as you cannot alter the function's ability to be called by reassigning `Function.prototype.call = () => {}`, since `%call%` is a native level implementation.

> Are the implementations more performant than it would be possible with Promise/generator function approach that is suggested by the proposal and is usually implemented in Babel and TypeScript?

It depends on js engine and its implemented compilation level optimizations and deoptimizations, but it's subject to continuous change, sometimes native implementation is slower than the 3rd party lib implementation, like [it happened with es5 `map, forEach` vs lodash counterparts](https://jsperf.com/native-map-vs-lodash-map), but in most cases native level implementation is unmatched due to being one level closer to machine code. As an example here is the  [2x prevalence of async-await in jsbench with async-await vs babel regenerator vs promise](http://jsbench.github.io/#bb78a677c5850d0830ff7d818d5ac4cd).

Comment: jsperf link is dead :(

Comment: @ŁukaszGodziejewski replaced with `jsbench`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, generator functions are used to imitate the behavior of `async/await`. When you use typescript, it will be compiled to javascript, and depending of your setup, it will compile `async/await` syntax to the generator implementation.

More about the compilation here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/async-await.html

So you should not worry about using them in typescript at all I think.

I guess native implementation does not use generators, it should be basically just syntax sugar for working with promises.

Comment: Yes, the question is about native implementations (low level). I wonder if they are more efficient than generators+promise constructors.