# Why does async/await break $http.get/the angular digest cycle?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, async-await, angular-promise

Have a look at the following Angular 1.x controller:

```
class RootController
{
    constructor($http)
    {
        this.variable = "apples";
        // this.test($http);      -- this works
        // this.asyncTest($http); -- this doesn't
    }

    async asyncTest($http)
    {
        await $http.get('/api/someApiCall');
        this.variable = "oranges";
        // await $http.get('/api/someApiCall'); -- this makes this method work
    }

    test($http)
    {
        $http.get('/api/someApiCall').then(() => {
            this.variable = "oranges";
        });
    }
}
```

If we uncomment one of the two commented out lines in the constructor, we get different behavior. If we run `test()`, then `variable` gets updates to the value "oranges" and displays in the view, as expected. If we run `asyncTest()`, the view continues to display "apples" until something forces a digest (for some reason clicking in and out of a textbox seems to do the trick).

Another weird issue is that if we uncomment out the second `await` in `asyncTest()`, then that method now works as expected.

Why does this happen, and why does the second `await` fix it? I thought `await` was pretty much just syntactic sugar for `then`, so these should be completely equivalent. I found some articles talking about this issue but they're more about how to fix it than what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Are you using Babel to transform Async Await ? If so, what plugin or transform are you using ?

Comment: @ajaybc Nope, this is all plain javascript. What I write is what the browser runs.

Comment: $http returns an Observable, async / await is for Promises. Try `await $http.get('').toPromise()`

Comment: @Baruch In [tag:angularjs] it returns an `HttpPromise`…

Comment: @deceze Oh, right.. I just assumed no one was working with a deprecated framework anymore.

Comment: "*I thought await was pretty much just syntactic sugar for `then`*, yes, pretty much, unless you are using angular promises. Because actually it is sugar for `NativePromise.resolve(…).then(…)`

Comment: @Baruch, you assume incorrectly, unfortunately

Comment: @BooBailey Ok, your point?

Comment: @Baruch, it's still useful to mention the difference for older frameworks.

Comment: as of June 2020, this AngularJS problem with Async/await is still unsolved, buggin me out.. heading https://ivantanev.com/async-functions-and-angularjs-1-x-do-not-mix/ hrere

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand Async Await functionality in Javascript is implemented using a clever combination of Promises and Generators which is too clever for me to explain in detail. But you can take a look at these if you are interested :
https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/d08c0304c5779223d6c468373af4815ec3ccdb84/src/js/harmony-async-await.js#34

https://curiosity-driven.org/promises-and-generators

[async/await native implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908575/async-await-native-implementations)

So since the Promise is resolved and the Angular dirty checking / digest cycle will be completed before the generator yields, your `this.variable = "oranges";` inside the `asyncTest` function wouldn't be reflected in the UI.
But when you add the commented out line `await $http.get('/api/someApiCall');` in the `asyncTest` function, the dirty checking / digest cycle will be triggered again, thereby updating the UI. The same thing happens when you focus out of some field like text boxes.

Since inside the `test` function you are doing `this.variable = "oranges";` inside the `then`, everything works fine.